# Formatting text table in file, merging two lines per row into one

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

I'm trying to write some information to a text file but the second row making spaces between the lines

The code :

```
private void CreateDriversList()
{
    StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(contentDirectory + "\\" + "Drivers.txt");
    w.WriteLine("Module Name  Display Name           Driver Type   Link Date");
    w.WriteLine("============ ====================== ============= ======================");
    //Declare, Search, and Get the Properties in Win32_SystemDriver
    System.Management.SelectQuery query = new System.Management.SelectQuery("Win32_SystemDriver");
    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject ManageObject in searcher.Get())
    {
        w.WriteLine(ManageObject["Name"].ToString());
        w.WriteLine("             " + ManageObject["DisplayName"].ToString());
    }
    w.Close();
}
```

Once i added the line :

```
w.WriteLine("             " + ManageObject["DisplayName"].ToString());
```

The result in the text file is like this :

```
Module Name  Display Name           Driver Type   Link Date
============ ====================== ============= ======================
1394ohci
             1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller
3ware
             3ware
ACPI
             Microsoft ACPI Driver
acpiex
             Microsoft ACPIEx Driver
acpipagr
```

Before i added the line the text file was like this :

```
Module Name  Display Name           Driver Type   Link Date
============ ====================== ============= ======================
1394ohci
3ware
ACPI
acpiex
acpipagr
AcpiPmi
```

I just wanted to add the Display Name row now so i added spaces so the row will start under Display Name but then its adding spaces in between the lines.

How can i solve it ?

**

In the end the text file should look like this :

```
Module Name  Display Name           Driver Type   Link Date             
============ ====================== ============= ======================
1394ohci     1394 OHCI Compliant Ho Kernel        7/26/2012 5:26:46 AM  
3ware        3ware                  Kernel        3/8/2012 10:33:45 PM  
ACPI         Microsoft ACPI Driver  Kernel        9/20/2012 9:09:16 AM  
acpiex       Microsoft ACPIEx Drive Kernel        7/26/2012 5:25:57 AM  
acpipagr     ACPI Processor Aggrega Kernel        7/26/2012 5:27:16 AM  
AcpiPmi      ACPI Power Meter Drive Kernel        7/26/2012 5:27:33 AM  
acpitime     ACPI Wake Alarm Driver Kernel        7/26/2012 5:27:37 AM
```

And in the display name row and maybe also in the moudle name row to make sure the names will be in one line full names.

For example in Display Name : 1394 OHCI Compliant Ho 
Should be : 1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller

**

```
Module Name  Display Name           Driver Type   Link Date
============ ====================== ============= ======================
1394ohci     1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller
3ware        3ware
ACPI         Microsoft ACPI Driver
acpiex       Microsoft ACPIEx Driver
acpipagr     ACPI Processor Aggregator Driver
AcpiPmi      ACPI Power Meter Driver
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've called `WriteLine` twice in your loop - so it's adding two lines for each item. You only want to add *one* line, e.g.

```
w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", ManageObject["Name"], ManageObject["DisplayName"]);
```

That won't pad the spaces though, so you need to include an alignment aspect in the [composite format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx). You want left padding, so you need a negative alignment, and it looks like you want 12 characters before the space, so:

```
w.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1}", ManageObject["Name"], ManageObject["DisplayName"]);
```

Comment: Jon Skeet your solution is working now i have to move the titles Driver Type and Link Date more to  the right and how do i add more characters to the next rows to the Driver Type and the Link Date ? For example {1,-7} ?  and i updated my question with how the text file look like now.

Comment: @HaimKashi: If you need to fit *all* the values on, you'll need to work out the maximum length first. If you've got a maximum length to start with, that would make life easier. But for the alignment stuff, I think now is a good idea for you to do more research yourself rather than me just spoonfeeding you the solution. If you follow the link to the MSDN article on composite format strings, you'll find a lot of information there.

Answer (score 4):

Using `WriteLine` will always append a new line character, so a simple solution is to use `Write` instead. You can use [`PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a.aspx) to fix the width first field until it's the right size:

```
w.Write(ManageObject["Name"].ToString().PadRight(13, ' '));
w.WriteLine(ManageObject["DisplayName"]);
```

But for a better solution to fixing the width of each field, I'd recommend using a formatting string instead:

```
w.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1}", ManageObject["Name"], ManageObject["DisplayName"]);
```

The `{0,x}` syntax will only pad characters to the end of your input parameters. It won't truncate them if they are too long. This can lead to some problems if the `DisplayName` is longer than the allotted space for the column. You can use [`String.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc.aspx) to truncate the string to an appropriate length. In the end your full code would look something like this:

```
w.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-22} {2,13}, {3,22:M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt}",
    ManageObject["Name"].ToString().Remove(12),        // Truncate to 12 chars
    ManageObject["DisplayName"].ToString().Remove(22), // Truncate to 22 chars
    ManageObject["DriverType"].ToString().Remove(13),  // Truncate to 13 chars
    ManageObject["LinkDate"]                       // No need to truncate here
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found A Great solution for these type of problems 
[C# Function to create formatted table in Text File](http://dotnetdiary.wordpress.com/2009/12/15/c-function-to-create-formatted-table-in-text-file/)